# Private HTTP/POST

Tags: php, javascript, post

I have an HTML code that request to PHP server. I want to just attend requests done my HTML code, not the others. I thought doing something like a token with javascript and answer just for correct tokens, but I have a problem: I use MediaWiki and the javascript code is "open source" (and yes, the POST request is done from the MediaWiki).

Does anyone know how to do a private POST request?

Comment: Other than the token you already thought of, you can only really do this by checking `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']`, but that is unreliable  too. As long as your script doesn't have any authorization or IP restriction, you can't easily prevent requests to it.

Comment: Is there any way to get *reliable* information about the person who did the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a random token like

`$_SESSION['token']=sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));`

Put the token value in a hidden input

`<input type='hidden' name='token' value=$_SESSION['token'] />`

Then, in your php check if the token was sent

```
if($_REQUEST['token']!=$_SESSION['token']){
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "Request from other site ...");
    die("Request failed. (Disabled cookies?) Contact administrator: ...");
}
```

Look this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Answer (score 0):

You want to hear about [authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

Comment: As it is a MediaWiki, no authentication is required.